# Which formula is correct for the order 5 of the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have a Lie Algebra with a basis:
$$
A_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \
A_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \
A_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The Lie brackets are $[A_1,A_2]$ = $A_3$ ; $[A_1,A_3] = A_1$ and $[A_3,A_2] = A_2$.

I want to compute $\log(\exp(A_1)\exp(A_2))$. I tried using the well known Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula until order 5 (with the terms already computed as on wikipedia) and also the Tables 1 and 2 of the paper '[An efficient algorithm for computing the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff series and some of its applications](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3078418)' from Casas and Murua published in 2009. The three terms of order 5 that I get are different.

Could someone confirm that or explain the mistakes that I made in the computations? I am trying to determine if there is a mistake in the results given in the paper. My computations are as follows:

The well-known result (from Wikipedia for instance) gives at order 5 (in terms of right-nested commutators):
$$
\frac{[A_2, A_1, A_2, A_1,A_2] + [A_1, A_2, A_1,A_2,A_1]}{120} = \frac{A_1 + A_2}{120}.
$$

The result using Table 1 of the paper gives at order 5:
$$
\frac{[[[[A_2, A_1], A_1], A_2], A_2]}{180} - \frac{[[[A_2, A_1], A_1], [A_1, A_2]]}{120} - \frac{[[[A_2, A_1], A_2], [A_1, A_2]]}{360} = \frac{A_2}{180} - \frac{A_1}{120} - \frac{A_2}{360} = - \frac{A_1}{120} + \frac{A_2}{360}.
$$

The result using Table 2 of the paper gives at order 5:
$$
\frac{[A_1, [A_1, [[A_1, A_2], A_2]]]}{180} + \frac{[[A_1, A_2], [[A_1, A_2], A_2]]}{120} + \frac{[[A_1, [A_1, A_2]], [A_1, A_2]]}{360} = \frac{A_1}{360} + \frac{A_2}{120} + \frac{A_1}{180} = \frac{3 A_1}{360} + \frac{A_2}{120}.
$$

Comment: Have you checked that these elements belong to the domain of convergence of the BCH formula?

Comment: I did not verify it formally but numerically it works.

Comment: Maybe playing with $tA_i$ for $t\in [0,1]$ could help. For small $t$, the BCH formula holds. If not, there's an error somewhere. Practically, I'd check with $t=1/2$, then with $t=3/4$ or $1/4$ according to whether equality holds for $t=1/2$. If equality holds for small values of $t$, the issue is possibly an issue of convergence, while if it fails even for small $t$, there's a computation mistake at some point.